# probability counters out of a bag

Tags: probability

hi this is basic but I cannot get back into my mind set!

> There are $12$ counters in a bag.
>
> - $3$ of the counters are red
> - $1$ is blue
> - $2$ are yellow
> - rest are green.
>
> Someone takes $1$ counter out at random.  Show the probability that that counter is  yellow or green is $2/3$.

So $50\%$ chance of it being green & $16.6\%$ chance of it being yellow. So am I right in thinking it is green or yellow is $2/3$? Is it that simple?

Comment: Did you mean to say *"So $50\%$ chance of it being green & $16.6\%$ chance of it being yellow.. so am I right in thinking it is green or yellow is $2/3$? Is it that simple?"* ?  If so, it might be worth explaining where the $50\%$ and  $16.6\%$ come from

Comment: I got the 50% because the green counters are 6 out of 12. And the yellow counters are 2 out of 12 so I changed both into percentages? But the question was "show that the probability that this counter is yellow or green is 2/3".

Comment: OK - so you had a green/yellow typo.  Your explanation completes the calculation: alternatively you could have said there are $8$ green and yellow  counters out of $12$ total counters making the probability $\frac23$

Comment: Oh I see !! Thanks I did not understand how the question was written, I thought it was asking me to show that yellow was 2/3 or green was 2/3 individually! But yes thank you very much.